# How to create Custom Document(_document.tsx) in Nextjs 13+

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a React Portal in Nextjs 13+ app, but there are no more local app/pages folder in which you would usually create Custom Document(_document.tsx) file. Instead its already created in server side, outside of src directory.

Or is there a better way of dealing with that problem?

Right now I'm having an error when clicking on a button that opens modal:

`Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Target container is not a DOM element.`

My current _document.tsx is located in src/app directory and it has code:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
    return (
        

        <Html>
            <Head />
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
                <div id='portal' />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}
```

And then I have a Modal.tsx file,

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

type PropsType = {
    active: boolean
    setActive: (arg: boolean) => void
    children: ReactElement
}

function Modal({ active, setActive, children }: PropsType) {
    const [domReady, setDomReady] = useState(false)
    const ref = useRef<Element | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('portal')
        setDomReady(true)
    }, [])

    return domReady && typeof window === 'object'
        ? createPortal(
                <div
                    className={active ? 'modal active' : 'modal'}
                    onClick={() => setActive(false)}
                >
                    <div
                        className={active ? 'modal__content active' : 'modal__content'}
                        onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
                    >
                        {children}
                    </div>
                </div>,
                document.getElementById('portal')!
          )
        : null
}

export default Modal
```

EDIT: So I kinda fixed it, by creating div with an id of 'portal' inside layout.tsx

`<div id='portal'></div>`

But the problem with such approach is that I always have said empty div rendered on my page.